# How do I make App.config values visible for referenced ClassLibraires (Assebmlies)

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a C# Project called `Application` which is basically considered to represent the top most application layer. All other Layers are treated as ClassLibraries like `BUSINESS`, `DAO` and `UTIL`. Now I want that the application be configurable by using the ***App.config*** file. For that purpose I need to make this configuration file visible for the referenced ClassLibraries (Assemblies).

For me, the most suitable solution would be that the `UTIL` assembly has access to the App.config and is able to share those accessible items to the upper application layers.

So far I tried to create a ***Settings.settings*** file in the `UTIL` assembly which defines one item: `Name: ElemName; Type: String; Scope: Application`. The ***App.config*** file which is located within the `Application` assembly contains the following source:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <UTIL.Settings>
    <setting name="ElemName" serializesAs="String">
      <value>SomeValue</value>
    </setting>
  </UTIL.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

If I now try to access this property via: `Settings.Default.ElemName`,
the build fails with error: **'UTIL.Settings' is inaccessible due to its protection level**

A further approach, to make this property visible via a helper class inside assembly `UTIL`

```
public String GetElemName()
{
  return Settings.Default.ElemName;
}
```

fails with an: **'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll ... Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize**

How can I get it running? (I only need to read the configuration)

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use AppSettings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried it, and it gives the same Error: `'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll ... Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize`

Comment: That error means that you misspelled your XML file. Most probably you have a stray `>` or forgot a closing tag or nested elements in an invalid way.

Comment: instead of applicationSettings try using appSettings with https://cfg.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in a different way.

The Project called `Application` still contains the App.config file. All referenced assemblies (`Business`, `DAO`, `UTIL`, and TestAssemblies) just share the applications configuration.

---

**How to share configuration:**

1. Project (`Business`, `DAO`, `UTIL`, etc.) -> Add -> Existing Item -> 'Select' App.config -> Add As Link
2. Project -> Add Reference -> .NET -> System.Configuration -> OK
3. `string configValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];`

---

**How the App.config file looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="token" value="ConfigValue" />
  </appSettings>
...
</configuration>
```

---

Without this reference to the existing App.conifg file `AppSettings["token"]` won't resolve the value while running with NUnit. If the application is started in debug mode, everything works fine, even without the link to App.config as mentioned by user ***`Maarten`***

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is the following:

Add the required settings in the project properties of the DLL assemblies like you would do for any normal application.

Now, a DLL doesn't actually *read* its own `app.config`. The trick is to copy the entire `<applicationSettings>` block from the DLLs `app.config` to the application's `app.config` and also add the respective line in the `<sectionGroup>` section at the top of the file.

---

Example: Let's assume the `app.config` for your DLL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <applicationSettings>
        <DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="AllowStart" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And the `app.config` of your application looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="App.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>        
    <App.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Temp</value>
      </setting>
    </App.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

After the above described changes, the application's config file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="App.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <applicationSettings>        
    <App.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Temp</value>
      </setting>
    </App.Properties.Settings>
    <DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="AllowStart" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
    </DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

**From both your application and DLL code you'll be able to use the normal configuration settings mechanism, like access a value through `Properties.Settings.Default.AllowStart` from the DLL's code or `Properties.Settings.Default.LogPath` from the application's code.**

Two things you can not do:

1. Access the DLL config values from your application and vice versa
2. Manage the DLLs config values from the application's property page. You need to edit the `app.config` manually to add/remove/modify settings.

---

Connection strings, by the way, can also be managed that way. I've added to the examples above.