# C# Changing value in dll.config isnt changing at runtime

Tags: c#

I have configured a boolean variable in project's settings file
when I compile, in my output folder i see the variable in the .dll.config, as follows:

```
      <setting name="ShowStats" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
      </setting>
```

In code I refer to it by `Properties.Settings.Default.ShowStats`
I want to be able to change my .config file and write there `False` or `True`, and to have this value reflected in runtime.
it seems that only changing it from my Settings window in Visual Studio will work in runtime.
Changing with notepad isnt working. it will always be the last value set in VS Settings window.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you editing the app.config file in your project or the exename.exe.config file in the project output?

Comment: My solution is just a dll, which is part of a more general project. The config Im editing is the one belongs to my dll. i.e a.dll, a.dll.config, which I edit. my exe is something else, b.exe

Answer (score 5):

Dlls don't actually have config files. Only the entry process has a config file. Basically: your entries need to be copied from the dll-named config file into app.config, or the exe-named config file.

Further: these values are only read at startup; if you are changing it *while running*, that won't do anything (unless the process chooses to restart itself by monitoring configuration - asp.net does this).

Answer (score 2):

DLLs can not have config files. While they will be created by Visual Studio, they will not be read at runtime. You need to merge the DLLs configuration into the application's configuration.

The settings will keep their default values if you don't merge the configuration. I've answered how to do this here: [How do I make App.config values visible for referenced ClassLibraires (Assebmlies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838922/how-do-i-make-app-config-values-visible-for-referenced-classlibraires-assebmlie/19839327#19839327) (It is, however, not the accepted answer in this case)

Please note: +1 for accessing settings by `Settings.Default...` instead of `ConfigurationManager`.

Example for merging the configurations taken from my answer to the question linked above: Let's assume the `app.config` for your DLL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <applicationSettings>
        <DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="AllowStart" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

And the `app.config` of your application looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="App.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>        
    <App.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Temp</value>
      </setting>
    </App.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

After the above described changes, the application's config file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="App.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DLLSample.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <applicationSettings>        
    <App.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="LogPath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Temp</value>
      </setting>
    </App.Properties.Settings>
    <DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="AllowStart" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
    </DLLSample.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

**From both your application and DLL code you'll be able to use the normal configuration settings mechanism, like access a value through `Properties.Settings.Default.AllowStart` from the DLL's code or `Properties.Settings.Default.LogPath` from the application's code.**

Two things you can not do:

1. Access the DLL config values from your application and vice versa
2. Manage the DLLs config values from the application's property page. You need to edit the `app.config` manually to add/remove/modify settings.

Answer (score 1):

`.config` files are read once on startup at runtime by the `ConfigurationManager`. Also if you are using a main `app.config` for your application you need to actually add your individual `dll.config` values under the correct section heading to the `app.config` in order for the application to pick them up at runtime.

Changing the file at runtime still will have no effect, unless you write your application to do so with manually written code (`FileSystemWatcher` etc). Only changing ASP.NET `web.config` files results in the runtime application restarting as it's a feature of ASP.NET's runtime.