Manually Changed APP.CONFIG Not Reflected in APP
I have a Vb.NET VSTO project that has one setting in an App.Config file. Let's say the string setting is named TestSetting. I publish and install the project. When the application is not running, I modify the TestSetting value from MyValue to MyRedefinedValue. When I open the application again, if I reference the TestSetting, it returns MyValue instead of MyRedefinedValue.
AccessModifier = Public
Scope = User
Why would that be the case?

I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500384/c-sharp-changing-value-in-dll-config-isnt-changing-at-runtime

You should either delete your question as a duplicate or post an actual answer. Don't leave a question unanswered when the problem has been resolved.

This question is similar to: C# Changing value in dll.config isnt changing at runtime. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
